# SESSION is not working in Plesk site preview

Tags: php, session, plesk

hi i am using site preview , where everything is working fine.

But session is not at all working.

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: What is "site preview"? What is not working with session, what do you expect session to do that it is not doing?

Comment: Does "Plesk Site Preview" supports sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plesk Site Preview does not support SESSION, sorry.

You can use your hosts file to preview your site (as long as there is no redirecting) like explained [here](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/61/How+can+I+test%7B47%7Dpreview+my+website+before+switching+DNS?#gs/url-dependency-and-using-your-hosts-file-for-previ) under "URL dependency and using your HOSTS file for previews".

Comment: i have my hosting account. but haven't yet assign name server to my domain.But i have to test how my code is working.So i used site preview.